# Mac OS X - NPM + Jasmine not staying installed. Have to reinstall every time terminal closes

Tags: javascript, macos, npm, terminal, jasmine

This isn't a very fun question to figure out, but basically I'm trying to run spec.js tests and if I come back to it a day later I have to reinstall both NPM and Jasmine. Clearly this isn't the worst thing in the world but it's pretty annoying and I'm worried I'm missing something more serious by ignoring this. Googling for this specific issue seems impossible, assuming anyone has asked before.

Thank you.

```
myfolder@Jacob calculator % npm --version
zsh: command not found: npm
myfolder@Jacob calculator % jasmine -v
zsh: command not found: jasmine
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not installed any more? Maybe it is not available globally? How are you installing it?

Comment: How do you instal it? Through homebrew, ports, some bash scripts from whenever?

Comment: I install nvm using this bash script `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
`  Then install node using `nvm install node` and run with `nvm use node`.  Then I install jasmine using `npm install -g jasmine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Had a fundamental misunderstanding as to what was happening when I installed Node. I was installing... but I wasn't *initializing* when I restarted the terminal. So a) it wasn't being removed and b) I didn't realize I had to initialize it every time.

To fix that, look at [this website](https://itnext.io/nvm-the-easiest-way-to-switch-node-js-environments-on-your-machine-in-a-flash-17babb7d5f1b). It very simply explains how to have nvm initialize every time you open Terminal if you're like me and it isn't working. Just skip ahead to "Step 2".